# Where do I find, and how do I setup VS with a more "attractive" UI controls?

Tags: webforms

So today I can create a website using VS and drag and drop some ugly outdated buttons and form elements (e.g. that standard grey button, and square non styled text boxes and drop downs). I know you could replace a button with a graphic, but im no graphic designer. I want to be able to download and install some free plugin/extension that will give me a bunch of different "cool" looking options for buttons (and all the other standard form controls). So in short, I dont need new controls per say (though they are welcome and encouraged as well) but rather, I simply want a bunch of different "cool looking" visual options for the existing .net form controls, so I can make a website that doesn't look like its 90's.

I use vs 05 and 08.

Answer (score 1):

for free controls have a look at codeplex:

http://dj.codeplex.com

http://yuidotnet.codeplex.com

for commercial level controls, Telerik, DevExpress, Infragistics...